# On specific domain, SFTP works but Nautilus is unable to connect

Tags: sftp

SFTP works for me in general, and I have Nautilus working for several of the remote clusters I use.

However, Nautilus throws `Unable to access location: Permission denied` when I enter `sftp://[username]@[domain]`.

Additionally, I am able to use SFTP from the command line with this server without issue (using `sftp [username]@[domain]`), so this must be Nautilus-specific and server-specific.

It's also worth noting that this cluster requires a valid Kerberos ticket to login, which I have obtained. Do I need to tell Nautilus where this ticket is somehow?

Comment: Check if Nautilus is choking by enabling the debug logs like https://askubuntu.com/a/1142299/883853 . And just to make sure, can it use kerberos for sftp to other servers? I thought it (and the underlying `gvfs-mount`) only supported kerberos for smb, but haven't tried. If you have access to the server logs, you may be able to see whether nautilus is attempting kerberos as an authentication type

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using for command-line `sftp`, and where is your ticket cache located?